# elementary os not booting or login Screen not Display

Tags: boot, display, greeter

[image]

When I am turning on the laptop, my screen shows the only attachment image.

And Ctrl+Alt+F1 also not working.

it that any way to rest my ELEMENTARY OS

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "splash guiet" flags in the grub entry on boot to see boot logging output to see possible errors.

Get to edit grub entry by pressing one of those
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/key-to-show-grub-menu-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Just after the BIOS splash screen comes up, where you are told to hit Del, F2, F3 whatever to get to the BIOS) press ESC several times. That will allow you to a SAFE or RESTORE mode.